# Routes are not initialized

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following setup:

[image: Solution structure]

Which is pretty simple. Now the situation I am facing is quite strange. If I place the Startup file in the **Test** project I get a 404 for all the routes, if I move that file to the **WebApplication1** all routes are found.

This is what the Startup class looks like:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;

namespace Test
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseSwagger();

            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), 
            // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

I can't give any more details because that's all I have. Moving the class from one project to the other create an issue and I can't see why.

The test project is just a class library:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**UPDATE**

The question, just to make it clear, is why does moving the Startup class to the Test project stops the routes being initialized?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

The Test project is actually just a Common set of base classes for web project, sorry for the wrong name. So if I moved the Startup class from the Common.Web project to WebApplication1 and update the namespaces all works fine, doing the otherwise stops it from working. Debugging shows the Startup class being called which is even more odd.

[image: Solution structure]

Comment: Startup is meant for the web application. And as indicated by its name it is part of the start up process for the web application.

Comment: The project is badly named... It is supposed to a class library where I have all the classes needed to start new application projects. I will updated the image to. Also, the WebApplication1 is the start project.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I am trying to figure out what it is you are actually trying to do.

Comment: See if it is more clear, I added a new image. Basically I am porting a set of Web Api 2 base classes (startup, filters  and so on), and started with the basics. A common library where I have a Startup class which the WebApplication1 is making a reference to. It should work normally, I mean I just moved it to a different assembly but the code to start the Host is still in the Program class.

Comment: IMHO, you shouldn't move `Startup` to class library, why want you do this? Anyway, `app.UseMvc();` might use your current assembly, you should check that.

Comment: @YuriyN. Always did that with the old Web Api 2 projects and had no issues. We have multiple Apis and we use nugets to make sure they all look the same, we dont want replication, so yes I need to move that class. That might be the cause for the issue alright, need to check it. Thanks

Comment: @YuriyN. Actually this was the same behavior in the Web Api 2, might need to setup the ioc for the controllers, I just thought it was being done upfront

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working, this is what fixed it:

```
public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var mvcModule = services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    foreach(var assembly in EndpointAssemblies)
    {
        mvcModule.AddApplicationPart(assembly);
    }
```

Where EndpointAssemblies is just a list of defined assemblies.
        mvcModule.AddControllersAsServices();
    }